# LWC: Error accessing Inner class from javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, inner-class

Im running into the following javascript error when trying to display inner class data on my LWC. This was working fine until I added ".data" to my output variables for employerAddress to resolve another issue. All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Error:  [Cannot read property 'employerAddress' of undefined]

```
public with sharing class Onboarding {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<OnboardingPeopleResult> getpeople(String recordId) {

        List<String> rolelist = new List<String>();

        List<OnboardingPeopleResult> oprList = new List<OnboardingPeopleResult>(); 

        OnboardingPeopleResult oprobj = new OnboardingPeopleResult();

        for(AccountContactRelation acr : [select Id, AccountId, Contact.Firstname, 
            Contact.Lastname
            from AccountContactRelation 
            where AccountId =: recordId]){

            oprobj = new OnboardingPeopleResult();

            oprobj.accountid = acr.Contact.AccountId;
            oprobj.firstname = acr.Contact.Firstname;
            oprobj.lastname = acr.Contact.Lastname;

            oprobj.entityname = acr.Contact.Entity_Name__c;
            oprobj.employerAddress = new OnboardingAddressResult();
            oprobj.employerAddress.street1 = '101 Test St.';

            oprList.add(oprobj);

        }

        return oprList;
    }

}
```

```
//Outer Class
public class OnboardingPeopleResult {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String accountid {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String firstname {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String lastname {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public OnboardingAddressResult employerAddress {get;set;}

    public OnboardingPeopleResult() { //String accountid, String firstname, String lastnameAccount client, Account pa, AccountConctactRelationship acr
        this.accountid = '';
        this.firstname = '';
        this.lastname = '';
        this.middlename = '';
        this.employerAddress = new OnboardingAddressResult();
    }

}
```

```
//Inner Class
public class OnboardingAddressResult {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string customname{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string street1{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string street2{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string city{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string state{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string postalcode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public integer key {get;set;}

    public OnboardingAddressResult() {

        this.customname = '';
        this.street1 = '';
        this.street2 = '';
        this.city = '';
        this.state = '';
        this.postalcode = '';
        this.key = 0;

    }

}
```

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api} from 'lwc';

import getpeople from '@salesforce/apex/Onboarding.getpeople';

export default class OnboardingPeople extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api people = [];
    @api record = {};
    @track error;
    @track bShowModal = false;
    @track value;

    @track columns = [
        {
            label: 'Action',
            type: 'button-icon',
            initialWidth: 75,
            typeAttributes: {
                iconName: 'action:edit',
                title: 'Edit',
                variant: 'border-filled',
                alternativeText: 'Action'
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'First Name',
            fieldName: 'nameUrl',
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'firstname' }, 
            target: '_blank'},
            sortable: false
        },
        {
            label: 'Last Name',
            fieldName: 'lastname',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: false
        },
        {
            label: 'Roles',
            fieldName: 'roles',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: false
        }

    ];

    @wire(getpeople,{recordId:'$recordId'}) 
    wiredPeople({error, data}){
        if(data){
            this.people = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {

            this.people = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

     // Row Action event to show the details of the record
    handleRowAction(event) {
        const row = event.detail.row;
        console.log('row-->'+JSON.stringify(row));
        this.record = row;
        this.bShowModal = true; // display modal window
    }

}
```

```
<template>

    <!-- Lightning Data Table -->
    <lightning-card title="People"> 
        <lightning-datatable data={people} 
                             columns={columns} 
                             key-field="accountid"
                             hide-checkbox-column="true"
                             onrowaction={handleRowAction}></lightning-datatable> 
    </lightning-card> 

    <!-- Edit Record Modal Window --> 
    <template if:true={bShowModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
                 aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
                 aria-modal="true"
                 aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
                class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large">
           <div class="slds-modal__container">
              <!-- modal header start -->
              <header class="slds-modal__header">
                 <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" variant="inverse" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                 </button>
                 <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{record.firstname} {record.lastname}</h2>
              </header>
              <!-- modal body start -->
              <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">

                <div class="c-container">
                    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Personal Information</h3>
                    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                        <lightning-layout-item  size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="4">
                            <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input data-formfield="firstname" name="fname" type="text" label="First" value={record.firstname} onchange={handleSavePerson}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>

                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="4">
                                <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input type="text" label="Last" value={record.lastname}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>

                    </lightning-layout>


                    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="3" large-device-size="3">
                            <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input type="text" label="Street" value={record.data.employerAddress.street1}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="3" large-device-size="3">
                            <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input type="text" label="City" value={record.data.employerAddress.city}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="3" large-device-size="3">
                            <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input type="text" label="State" value={record.data.employerAddress.state}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="3" large-device-size="3">
                            <div class="custom-pad"><lightning-input type="text" label="Postal Code" value={record.data.employerAddress.postalcode}></lightning-input></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </lightning-layout>


                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- modal footer start-->
              <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                   <lightning-button variant="brand"
                    label="Close"
                    title="Close"
                    onclick={closeModal}
                    ></lightning-button>
              </footer>
           </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
     </template>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using record.data use “record. OnboardingAddressResult.EmployerAddress.Street1”

I think that should work.

Comment: If I remove it then I get the following issue. How can I do this to resolve this issue along with the issue from my previous post? I need to be able to edit existing records yet create new ones as well using custom classes.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285061/lwc-inner-class-property-access-issue